# When is a reference to the object class required?

Tags: java, oop, object

What is the function of the class `Object` in java? All the "objects" of any user defined class have the same function as the aforementioned class .So why did the creators of java create this class?
In which situations should one use the class 'Object'?

Comment: What class do you think should be the superclass of all other classes?

Comment: Are you asking why every type is a subtype of `Object`, or why it's concrete rather than `abstract` or an `interface`? Or perhaps something else entirely?

Comment: Where do you think all user created objects get those methods? they inherit them because they are subclasses of Object.

Comment: There are literally thousands of hits on Google answering this exact question. This is java 101 stuff.

Comment: @delnan I came across a piece of code where they used a reference of the 'Object' class to synchronize threads. They could have used the object of the same class as well.This is what confused me.

Comment: @HotLicks Do you mean it provides a skeleton for all other classes?

Comment: @JaneLove That's correct. It's unclear whether you're asking about the purpose of the entire `class Object` or about when you'd use `Object foo = new Object();`.

Comment: @redFIVE I've seen quite a few questions on this forum that have many hits on google  . Yet people have answered them and given exceedingly better explanations than those google links.Surprisingly, they have got many upvotes too!

Comment: For `synchronized` all you need is some common object.  If there isn't one it's sufficient to create an Object and use that (so long as everyone synchronizing on that critical data uses the same Object).  Or you can use a Kumquat, if one of those is laying around handy.

Comment: @chrylis I wanted to know the purpose of the entire class 'Object'

Comment: You need to learn how to ask better questions.  "Why have Object" is different from "Why is an Object referenced in a synchronized statement".

Comment: If you have to ask "Why have Object", you do not comprehend objects in general, the concept of an object hierarchy, and the meaning of "object oriented".

Comment: @HotLicks You're correct.I'll frame my questions better next time

Comment: @HotLicks   An OO language isn't required to have a single root class.   Consider C++.  For that reason, I think "Why have an Object class" in an OO language is an interesting question.

Comment: @lreeder - No, but C++ suffers a fair amount of confusion due to not having a single root class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since all classes in Java are obligated to derive (directly or indirectly) from `Object`, it allows for a default implementation for a number of behaviours that are needed or useful for all objects (e.g. conversion to a string, or a hash generation function).

Furthermore, having all objects in the system with a common lineage allows one to work with objects in a general sense. This is very useful for developing all sorts of general applications and utilities. For example, you can build a general purpose cache utility that works with any possible object, without requiring users to implement a special interface.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty much the only time that `Object` is used raw is when it's used as a lock object (as in `Object foo = new Object(); synchronized(foo){...}`. The ability to use an object as the subject of a `synchronized` block is built in to `Object`, and there's no point to using anything more heavyweight there.

Answer (score 1):

`Object` provides an interface with functionality that the Java language designers felt all Java objects should provide.  You can use `Object` when you don't know the subtype of a class, and just want to treat it in a generic manner.  This was especially important before the Java language had generics support.

There's an [interesting post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/157450/why-all-classes-in-net-globally-inherits-from-object-class) on programmers.stackexchange.com about why this choice was made for .NET, and those decisions most likely hold relevance for the Java language.

Answer (score 1):

What Java implements is sometimes called a "cosmic  hierarchy". It means that all classes in Java share a common root.

This has merit by itself, for use in "generic" containers. Without templates or language supported generics these would be harder to implement.

It also provides some basic behaviour that all classes automatically share, like the toString method.

Having this common super class was back in 1996 seen as a bit of a novelty and cool thing, that helped Java get popular (although there were proponents for this cosmic hierarchy as well).